# How to wait for function to finish before executing another in componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-redux

I'm using React-Redux and have an action initializeApp that needs to be run for all pages:

```
export const initializeApp = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log("first initializeApp auth action");
  const response = await axios.get("/api/current_user");
  console.log("second initializeApp auth action");
  dispatch({
    type: SAVE_FETCHED_USER_AUTH,
    auth: response.data.auth,
    mongoDBUserId: response.data._id
  });
...
}
```

I have specific actions that need to be run for each page like:

```
export const fetchAsks = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log("fetchAsks action");
  const response = await axios.get("/api/landing_asks");
  dispatch({
    type: SAVE_FETCHED_ASKS,
    landingAsks: response.data
  });
};
```

In a React component file, I have:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // run once before first render()
    this.props.initializeApp();
    this.props.fetchLandingPageSortingHatAsks();
    console.log("after both componentWillMount functions");
}
```

I need initializeApp to finish running before fetchAsks, but in the console, it gets printed in this order:

1. "first initializeApp auth action"
2. "fetchAsks action"
3. "after both componentWillMount functions"
4. "second initializeApp auth action"

I need the order to be:

1. "first initializeApp auth action"
2. "second initializeApp auth action"
3. "fetchAsks action"
4. "after both componentWillMount functions"

I tried making initializeApp asynchronous by adding `async` before (), but actions cannot be asynchronous. Moving fetchAsks to componentDidMount also did not fix the problem.

Any help or direction is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `componentWillMount` is deprecated - you shouldn't be using it if you can avoid it (and you can avoid it!)

But to answer your question, your functions are asynchronous, but you're not actually waiting for any of them to complete. You probably want

```
componentWillMount() {
    // run once before first render()
    this.props.initializeApp().then(() => {
      this.props.fetchLandingPageSortingHatAsks();
      console.log("after both componentWillMount functions");
    });
}
```

Here, only after initializeApp() completes will the next function run in the `then()` callback.

Using callbacks, async/await and Promises are the only way to ensure asynchronous code executes in a specific order.

Comment: Hey Kirbee, I already tried using the `.then()` and it didn't work because the initializeAp function does not have `.then()`. Thank for you the note on componentWillMount.

Comment: Hi Hunter - what do you mean it doesn't have .then() ? You can use async/await or promise chaining as async/await is based on promises - what is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I'm using React-Redux, so the initializeApp is really an action. When I try to make the action asynchronous, I get an error; I don't think that actions can be asynchronous.

Comment: Ahhh, I see - you should definitely look into using [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) then!